# Public URL for download WSO2 API manager and WSO2 APIM Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently working on creating docker images for WSO2 APIM and APIM analytics distribution. For that I need to download the products through a wget command. Where can we download these products apart from the github release page.

Comment: You should be able to download from wso2.com product page. You have to mimic the post call happen when submit button clicked, using wget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 do not allow to download products via wget. (There are hacky ways you can, but it's not recommended.) If you need to download via wget, you should download the product from product page manually and host it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/2.1.0/wso2am-2.1.0.zip
```

For analytics

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/2.1.0/wso2am-analytics-2.1.0.zip
```

Try above.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.1.0

1.APIM 3.1.0

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/3.1.0/wso2am-analytics-3.1.0.zip
```

2.APIM ANALYTICS 3.1.0

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/api-manager/3.1.0/wso2am-analytics-3.1.0.zip
```

Comment: Please consider adding code formatting to your command. This is done by selecting the desired amount of text and clicking on the icon that looks like {}